# Run VBA macro whenever any workbook is opened

Tags: vba, excel

I've created an Excel add-in that attempts to run upon the opening of any and all workbooks that are opened during this session.  It works sometimes - but not always, and I don't know why.

I created a file, `addin.xlam`, and in this file, in `ThisWorkbook`, I have:

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

I then created a class module based off the code here:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If Not ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "New Quote") Then
            quoteCheck = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Quote Generator?", vbYesNo, "Quote Generator")
            If quoteCheck = vbYes Then
                prepare
            Else
                End
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If I close out of Excel and open a file from Windows Explorer, this line hits:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
```

And starts the code - if the workbook in question has "new quote" in its name, the macro runs.  Boom.  Perfect.

However, after this runs ONCE, if I open another workbook with the words "new quote", this private sub doesn't trigger. Why?

How do I get this to trigger *each time* I open **any** workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently opening a workbook doesn't automatically make it the active workbook, at least in time for this event handler to fire. Try this:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If Not Wb Is Nothing Then
    If InStr(Wb.Name, "New Quote") Then
        quoteCheck = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Quote Generator?", vbYesNo, "Quote Generator")
        If quoteCheck = vbYes Then
            prepare
        Else
            End
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: still nothing.  Even if I put a `stop` on the first line of `Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb as Workbook)` that `stop` doesn't trigger, so the sub itself is not firing.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that these subsequent workbooks are not being opened in the *add-ins* workbook collection

Comment: See my answer - I posted it as an answer so I could more easily add code.  Weird, sometimes I don't understand why Excel does the things it does......  I appreciate you helping me look into it though!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If Not ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "New Quote") Then
        quoteCheck = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Quote Generator?", vbYesNo, "Quote Generator")
        If quoteCheck = vbYes Then
            prepare
        Else
            '/ End '/REMOVE THIS LINE <--------------
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I'm not sure why this is - but when I checked "no" (so I didn't continue, as I was just testing this out), I ran `End` in the class module, and that stopped the Sub from re-firing until I restarted Excel.  Removing this `End` code now allows the `Private Sub` to fire each time I open a workbook....... weird.

Comment: It seems like you may have needed to use `Exit Sub` instead of `End` there. But it also looks like nothing else happens when that `If` statement evaluates to `False` anyways, so removing it altogether wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: yeah, `End`, `Exit Sub`, and [nothing at all] all do the same thing.....It works now so I'm not touching it :)

Comment: Using just `End` clears module-level variables so it probably clears your `App` variable so it no longer catches the events.