# Automatically run macro upon opening every Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Using a Personal workbook with macros, how do I make it so a macro runs as soon as you open any workbook? I've found not-quite-solutions to this (code is below), but it doesn't do what I need because it only works when you open Excel for the first time. I want to be able to keep Excel open, and any new workbooks that are opened will trigger a macro to run.

```
Sub workbook_open() 
MsgBox ("Hello.")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use a button to let the user select the workbook which the user want's to open. This will be way better than running code on opening ANY workbook (if that's even possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615594/run-vba-macro-whenever-any-workbook-is-opened

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`Workbook Open` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215.aspx). Please this in a workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
 Msgbox("Hello.")
 ' Whatever other code you like here too.
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the "Private" part do anything special? I already have this. It doesn't do what I want. I want the macro to run when a new workbook (other than Personal.xlsx) is opened.

Comment: @Robby you mean when *any* new workbook is opened, not just existing ones? Put the code in personal.xlsb I believe, and it'll launch on any new workbook opening IIRC

Comment: That only works if I close out of Excel completely and then open a workbook.

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: @lalebarde how not? Is it in a workbook module, where is your code stored? See the link under the OP posted by (at)Rdster