# How to execute a vba macro automatically only once at first file opening?

Tags: excel, vba

My use case is the following :

1. An Excel template which includes some post treatment VBA macro
2. A Python script that creates an Excel workbook from the above template
3. Desired process:

- Run the Python script
- Open the created workbook under Excel, which automatically run the VBA macro like depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40473473/1344633)
- Use the file and save it
- If I open the workbook again, the VBA macro shall not execute anymore

4. Justification : I am confortable at writing python scripts to build Excel workbooks, while the library I use misses some features. I want to minimize VBA code just to fill the gap.

So, **how to make my VBA macro execute only once at first workbook opening under Excel?**

My solution is to create a flag-like worksheet in the VBA macro, which I test the existence of at its beginning to exit or process. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be various other options, but a simple one would be to add a name `OpenFirstTime` with the value `True` to the Workbook and check if this value is `True` before you call your macro.

[image: Add name to the Workbook]

If it is, you call your procedure and toggle the value of the name to `False`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Evaluate("OpenFirstTime") = True Then
        'Call YourProcedure
        ThisWorkbook.Names("OpenFirstTime").Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```