# VBA - Internet Data Scrape & Download File & Copy Paste Data

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, download

**Summary:** We need to go to a website, download an Excel file, and copy&paste the data into an Excel template file all automatically.

**Current Problem:** My current VBA code opens IE, does the data **scrape** and downloads the file automatically without any problems. However, ONLY in Break Mode that it opens the downloaded workbook and copy&paste the data into the template.

**What Didn't Work:** I tried multiple ideas like Sleep, Application.Wait, and DoEvents. Unfortunately, it keeps getting stuck on the same line. The code does not recognize a Workbook has been open and can't find the data to copy&paste. Only after I enter into the Break Mode that the file will eventually open.

**Observation:** Security Settings on Excel removed so I do not receive a warning message when opening a file.

This snippet is part of a loop which will make the same procedure you will find below for 5 different files. After it downloads each file, it copies&paste the data into my template.

Any idea & solution is totally welcomed!

Please find my code below:

```
sub test()

'-----------------------------------
'Code to do the Data Scrape in here. It works fine.
'-----------------------------------

Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Dim h As Long
Dim wkbook As Workbook
Dim Cwkbook As String, ThisWkbook As String

'Code to Automate IE Download
Set o = New CUIAutomation
h = ieApp.hWnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke

'Download Completed and File Should be opened.
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:10 AM#
'Even after using DoEvents & Application.Wait, the code won't open the workbook until it goes into Break Mode.

'Code to find Downloaded Workbook which will come named either as X or Y.
ThisWkbook = ThisWorkbook.Name
For Each wkbook In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wkbook.Name, 9) = "XXXXXXXXX" Or Left(wkbook.Name, 9) = "YYYYYYYYY" Then
        Cwkbook = wkbook.Name
        '-----------------------------------
        'Code to Copy&Paste data in here. It works fine.
        '-----------------------------------
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

You will need the UIAutomationClient reference to make the code work. If you get an error when including it (like I did), add "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility" reference and run the code below:

```
Sub MyUIAutomation()

'----------------------------------------------------
'Add UIAutomation as VBA Reference
'----------------------------------------------------

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject

Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

VBProj.References.AddFromFile Environ("systemroot") & "/system32\uiautomationcore.dll"

Set VBProj = Nothing

End Sub
```

**UPDATE 8.28.17**: I tried a work around to copy/paste the data only when a Workbook is opened. The idea would be to finish my main "data extract" code. After the code is finished the Workbooks should open as it was behaving before, and the second code would trigger, copying/pasting the data.->
[Run VBA macro whenever any workbook is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615594/run-vba-macro-whenever-any-workbook-is-opened)

Outcome: It is still not working. It would only open the last workbook of the whole loop and copy&paste the data of it. The other 4 previous files wouldn't open.

**UPDATE 8.31.17** Another work around failed. I tried to create an User Form, where the user would have to click on 5 different buttons. The idea is to check if my problem was the looping. Each button would extract the file and after that my Copy&Paste Macro would trigger.

Outcome: It did not work as well. I figure that while I have my "User Form" open excel recognizes that a macro is running. If I run it under Break Mode it will still open the file and copy the data.

Comment: I will recommend you to reduce the scope of your problem... focus on what is not working, that way your code is easier to read & troubleshoot

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I just edited my post and tried to make it more straight forward.

Comment: Your code still is 70+ lines long, I'm sure your can further reduce that...

Comment: It is less than 50 lines now. I could remove the IE download automation piece. However, you wouldn't know how I am obtaining the file and if that might impact how Excel will find the file.

Comment: @HelderSepu I have some updates here on this code. Let me know if you have any idea on how to fix it! Thank you in advance for all the help

Comment: If some wanted to run your code what would it need to do? If I add it to an Excel module on I get an error on IUIAutomation

Comment: @HelderSepu check the new edits. I included an explanation on how to add the references I am using.

Comment: My comments are to help you write a better question and that way get attention from an expert in VBA (i'm not) you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be important to other people know that I found a solution to my own problem.

The main problem was that my original code was structured this way:

`'Open IE -> Search for a specific criteria -> Download File -> Open File -> Copy&Paste File.`

It would repeat the above procedure 5 times for each different file I need.

The code would run perfectly under break mode. However, when you actually ran it, it wouldn't bring over the data from the downloaded file.

**FIX:** It is a work around. I separated my code into pieces. The first piece is going to search, download, and open the file I want. The second piece will **only** trigger when a file with a specific name is opened. It will then perform all the remaining steps I need.

I used the Workbook_Open event to do such thing:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

The third and last piece, is a form created using shapes like circles, squares, and text box. It actually looks way nicer than an userform. Each circle performs like a button and will trigger the download of a specific file when clicked.

Now the code is structured like:

```
'1. Form using Shapes, each circle activates a specific script
'2. 5 Scripts -> Open IE, Search for a specific criteria, Download File, Open File
'3. 1 Script. Only Triggers when Excel Workbooks are opened. It will then only copy the data over if it meets certain criteria (such as filename).
```